# Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not worked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

I have an Web Api
And since I made all the settings according to the internet tutorial, but in JavaScript Fetch I still get the error
I put the following code in the web config:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />               
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

And i put the following code in the Global:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader
         (name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader
         (name: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true");
    }
```

Comment: "I still get the error" — What *specific* error. There are *lots* of CORS-related error messages.

Comment: @Quentin i'm sorry, i get this error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Comment: I would test in a different browser in the hope of getting a more informative error message then. That doesn't say if it was because it didn't find the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, or if the preflight had the wrong status code, or if it was a different header that was missing, or something else.